# How can I better manage memory usage when defining functions?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction

Suppose I have defined a numerical function `F[x]` that for each entry `x`, it takes a long time to calculate.

Suppose that now I want to define a new function using the previous one, say, `G[x_] := F[x]^2 + 2*F[x] + 1`.

My first question is, does Wolfram Mathematica calculate twice the value of `F[x]` to use it in `G[x]`? that is, first calculate the `F[x]` for `F[x]^2` and then the `F[x]` for the `2*F[x]`?

And if this is the case, how could I improve the way I define `G[x]` so that it only calculates `F[x]` once?

Comment: You can use *memoization* to evaluate it only once (`F[x_] := F[x] = ...`).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, putting the function call in twice will cause it to be evaluated twice. You can visualize this by putting a `Print` inside the function, for example:

```
f[x_] := (Print["In f"]; x)

g[x_] := f[x]^2 + 2*f[x] + 1

g[2]
 (* In f *)
 (* In f *)
 (* 2    *)
```

You can see that it went to `f` twice.
To avoid that, you can assign a temp variable:

```
g2[x_] := Module[{t = f[x]}, t^2 + 2*t + 1]

g2[2]
 (* In f *)
 (* 2    *)
```

Changing `f` to something slow, to illustrate the difference in timing:

```
f[a_] := NIntegrate[{Sin[x + y]/(1 + x^4 + y^4), (Sin[x] + Cos[y])/(
   1 + x^4 + y^4)}, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}]

g[1] // AbsoluteTiming
 (* {22.6585, {3.56334, 6.79898}} *)
g2[1] // AbsoluteTiming
 (* {11.2694, {3.56334, 6.79898}} *)
```

Comment: `With` instead of `Module` can give additional speed-up.

Comment: @Alx With `RepeatedTiming` I get exactly the same answer using `g3[x_] := With[{t = f[x]}, t^2 + 2*t + 1]` and `g2[x_] := Module[{t = f[x]}, t^2 + 2*t + 1]`. Is there a better way to write it?

Comment: I meant general advice to use `With` as it does just direct replacement and does not create additional variables `$smth` like `Module`. But you are right, in this case there is no difference.

Comment: WOW it never clicked until now! WHAT! This is AN AWESOME ANSWER

Comment: @CATrevillian Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like

```
G[x_] := a^2 + 2 a + 1 /. a -> F[x]
```

or

```
G[x_] := #^2 + 2 # + 1 &@F[x]
```